# Closing camera after a snapshot

Tags: python, opencv, tkinter, camera

I have this code below which creates a python gui to display a camera with a snapshot button. I would like to make it so that when a snapshot is taken the camera closes. I tried self.vid.release() and cv2.destroyAllWindows() inside the snapshot function. But it did not work. How can I close the camera after I take a snapshot?

```
import tkinter as tk
import cv2
import PIL.Image, PIL.ImageTk
import time

def camerachoice():
    class App:
        def __init__(self, window, window_title, video_source=0):
            self.window = window        
            self.window.title(window_title)
            self.video_source = video_source
            self.vid = MyVideoCapture(self.video_source)
            self.canvas = tk.Canvas(window, width = self.vid.width, height = self.vid.height)
            self.canvas.pack()
            self.btn_snapshot=tk.Button(window, text="Snapshot", width=50, command=self.snapshot)
            self.btn_snapshot.pack(anchor=tk.CENTER, expand=True)                       
            self.delay = 15
            self.update()


            self.window.mainloop()

        def snapshot(self):

            ret, frame = self.vid.get_frame()

            if ret:
                cv2.imwrite("frame-" + time.strftime("%d-%m-%Y-%H-%M- br%S") + ".jpg", cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR))


        def update(self):

            ret, frame = self.vid.get_frame()

            if ret:

                self.photo = PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage(image = PIL.Image.fromarray(frame))
                self.canvas.create_image(0, 0, image = self.photo, anchor = tk.NW)

            self.window.after(self.delay, self.update)


    class MyVideoCapture:
        def __init__(self, video_source=0):
            self.vid = cv2.VideoCapture(video_source)
            if not self.vid.isOpened():     
                raise ValueError("Unable to open video source", video_source)

            self.width = self.vid.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)
            self.height = self.vid.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)

        def get_frame(self):
            if self.vid.isOpened():
                ret, frame = self.vid.read()
                if ret:
                    return (ret, cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
                else:
                    return (ret, None)
            else:
                return (ret, None)

        def __del__(self):

            if self.vid.isOpened():
                self.vid.release()

#App()
    App(tk.Toplevel(), "Tkinter and OpenCV")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    camerachoice()
```

Comment: Do you want to close the camera or do you want to close the window? If you want to close the window, use `self.window.destroy()`. If you want to close the camera, change the tags on this question to reflect that.

Comment: Closing the window should close the camera processes, right? If so that works.

Comment: Closing the window just closes the window. It is better to first close the camera. That is why I suggested that you change the tags (which you did :D). I don't know much about `opencv` so I can't help you with that

Comment: Thank you anyways.

Comment: Your `self.vid.release()` will not work inside the snapshot method because `release` is not defined inside your `MyVideoCapture` class (Your `self.vid` inside the `App` class is currently holding the reference to `MyVideoCapture` object). I suggest you create a close method inside the `MyVideoCapture` and place your `self.vid.release()` inside that. Now call the close method from your snapshot method (eg: `self.vid.close()`).

Comment: Inside `snapshot()`, calls `del self.vid` which will in turn call `MyVideoCapture.__del__()`, then calls `self.window.destroy()`.

Comment: Thank you. The del self.vid worked.

Comment: @shub112 be careful when you delete a variable like that it can cause more problems in your case. It can throw `NameError` during the next update call. Which is one of the reasons I suggested you create another method to close the camera.